# how can i use gdb to to learn the size of the slots in an array?

Tags: c, gdb

I am looking at some C code that holds an array of names of other functions in the program.

```
myTypeDef myArrayName[3]={funcOne, funcTwo, funcThree};
```

How can I use GDB to learn how many bytes each slot in the array is?

Comment: Huh?  Each element is exactly `sizeof(myTypeDef)` bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `gdb` to find that out, the compiler knows it all along. Each "slot" of the array is `sizeof(myTypeDef)` bytes.

Comment: starting to really click. tx for help today